# StackTrace: how to show only my code?

Tags: asp.net, stack-trace

For debugging purposes I store exception's stack trace to log file in my ASP.NET application. But in most of cases it contains a looot of redundant information: stack trace of ASP.NET's core before my routines and System calls after.

Is there any way to trim this unrelevant, not in my assembly information from StackTrace object I create from Exception? I'm interested only in chunk of frames inside of whole trace.

Thank you.

Denis.

Comment: In your logger class, how do you output the stacktrace details? You can start filtering _irrelevant_ information there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way would be to create a [StackTrace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stacktrace.aspx) object, get the frames from it and loop through them, checking whether each frame was created for a method in one of your assemblies.

I don't think you really should do this though. You chould rather focus on getting less error messages in your logs than shortening them (which will likely make things more difficult to debug).

Comment: Matti, thank you for your answer. Okay, I'll write custom StackTrace.ToString() method that will loop through the frames. Unfortunately I can't get less error messages because I have exception-based logic here (thin ASP.NET layer just passes data to complex class library and processes exceptions to update UI).

Comment: @Denis: Maybe you rather shouldn't be logging all exceptions, but only the ones that your "logic" can't handle

Comment: I log exceptions for security purposes because website is highly sensitive financial service and our security team review every non-standard situation even just misspelt login or account details.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up parsing `ex.ToString()` and removing unwanted entries with Regex. It's not a universal solution, you have to specify each excluded entry manually, but it helps reduce size of logs and improve log readability. It's also fairly maintainable. Something like this:

```
private static string TrimStackTrace(Exception ex)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    string[] lines = ex.ToString().Split(Environment.NewLine, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    var excludeRegex = new Regex(@"^\s+at (Microsoft.AspNetCore|lambda_)");
    foreach (string line in lines)
    {
        if (excludeRegex.IsMatch(line))
        {
            continue;
        }

        sb.AppendLine(line);
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

You can of course make excluded entries part of your app config.